# Onde o eclipse C/C++ gera o executavel?

Tags: c++

Quero usar um relativo para abrir um arquivo para leitura no eclipse C/C++, mas precisaria saber onde o eclipse executa o arquivo para colocar o arquivo naquele diretório e usar a linha de código:

ifstream input("arquivo.txt");

ao invés de:

ifstream input("/home/caminho/workspace/programa/src/arquivo.txt");

Alguém pode me dizer onde o eclipse executa o código?